# percent (%) width rendered differently in different browser (firefox, safari, opera, chrome)

Tags: html, css

I use percent(%) in `div` `width` to wrap the `image` but the problem is every browser render it differently any suggestion why this happen. by the way `firefox` work perfectly but in `safari`, `chrome` and `opera` don't work the way that i want.

if possible can you give brief explanation why this happen!!

thank you in advance.....

below is the image show the problem:

[image]

html:

```
<div class="banner">
      <div class="divWrap">
        <div class="imageWrap noMarginLeft"><a href="#"><img src="images/130410_Project-tile1.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div class="imageWrap"><a href="#"><img src="images/130410_Project-tile2.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div class="imageWrap"><a href="#"><img src="images/130410_Project-tile3.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div class="imageWrap"><a href="#"><img src="images/130410_Project-tile4.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div class="imageWrap"><a href="#"><img src="images/130410_Project-tile5.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div class="imageWrap"><a href="#"><img src="images/130410_Project-tile6.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div class="imageWrap"><a href="#"><img src="images/130410_Project-tile7.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div class="imageWrap noMarginLeft"><a href="#"><img src="images/130410_Project-tile8.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div class="imageWrap"><a href="#"><img src="images/130410_Project-tile9.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div class="imageWrap"><a href="#"><img src="images/130410_Project-tile10.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div class="imageWrap"><a href="#"><img src="images/130410_Project-tile11.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div class="imageWrap"><a href="#"><img src="images/130410_Project-tile12.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div class="imageWrap"><a href="#"><img src="images/130410_Project-tile13.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div class="imageWrap"><a href="#"><img src="images/130410_Project-tile14.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div class="imageWrap noMarginLeft noMarginBottom"><a href="#"><img src="images/130410_Project-tile15.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div class="imageWrap noMarginBottom"><a href="#"><img src="images/130410_Project-tile16.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div class="imageWrap noMarginBottom"><a href="#"><img src="images/130410_Project-tile17.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div class="imageWrap noMarginBottom"><a href="#"><img src="images/130410_Project-tile18.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div class="imageWrap noMarginBottom"><a href="#"><img src="images/130410_Project-tile19.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div class="imageWrap noMarginBottom"><a href="#"><img src="images/130410_Project-tile20.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div class="imageWrap noMarginBottom"><a href="#"><img src="images/130410_Project-tile21.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
      </div>  

    </div><!-- end banner -->
```

css:

```
.banner{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}
.banner .imageWrap {
  float:left;
  width:13.772%;
  margin:0 0 0 .6%;
  background-color:#555
}

.banner .imageWrap img {
  float:left;
  max-width:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.noMarginLeft {margin-left:0 !important}
.noMarginBottom {margin-bottom:0 !important}
```

Comment: In that screenshot, are the browsers the same width......?

Comment: Try to add `position:relative` to `.banner`, `.imageWrap` and `.imageWrap img`.

Comment: give to live link or create a fiddle

Comment: I update the image with same width

Comment: do you use a reset stylesheet ? if not, then you should, otherwise you will always run into the problem that different browsers have different defaults for the element. (e.g. some browsers have border or padding for images in a link, others don't) especially if you use `%` width it will be easyer if all browsers have the same settings.

Comment: Why so many `float: left`s? It makes sense on the `.banner .imageWrap`, but on all the other things, I don't see the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browsers round percentage widths differently.

Here's an article on it from 2008 (but still relevant today):

http://robertnyman.com/2008/01/24/how-web-browsers-handle-rounding-when-it-comes-to-values-set-in-percentage/