# Div doesn't fill container 100% of the way when shrunk

Tags: html, css

Let's say hypothetically you have 5 divs.  One is a container and the other four are children.  You've set each one to be 25% of the container and you've given each one a background separate from the container background.

When you resize the browser your 4 divs at some point in time do not go all the way across, they might be a couple pixels off.   Is there a way to stop this form happening?  I'm assuming it's happening because it's 'snapping to each pixel' therefore leaving a small gap when resizing the browser.

[image: 25% width not going all the way across]

```
#container { 
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
}
.children {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    background: #fff;
 }
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AEvUL/

Screenshot of JSFiddle page in safari: http://cl.ly/image/1o1O2O401E0f

Comment: A small gap? Don't think that happens. Might be something wrong in your code. Can you show it?

Comment: Added code and jsfiddle demo

Comment: I don't see any, in fox or in chrome, do you have other styles in your stylesheet?

Comment: Try clicking and shrinking and resizing, it always shows up for me.  I'm in safari btw

Comment: This occurs only when you zoom in, correct? It's a known problem because of rounding errors. No solution exists (as far as I know)

Comment: Still, no reproduce...

Comment: Can't get it to happen in chrome, but it happens in safari.  No I am not zooming in

Comment: Added a screenshot of jsfiddle page in safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John Resig has a post about this issue that uses this exact case as its example.

http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/

> Take the following page for example. You have 4 floated divs, each
>   with a width of 25%, contained within a parent div of width 50px.
>   Here’s the question: How wide are each of the divs?
>
> The problem lies in the fact that each div should be, approximately,
>   12.5px wide and since technology isn’t at a level where we can start rendering at the sub-pixel level we tend to have to round off the
>   number. The problem then becomes: Which way do you round the number?
>   Up, down, or a mixture of the two? I think the results will surprise
>   you, as they did me.

There are also several Stack Overflow questions on the subject:

- [safari rounding down on subpixel calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839847/safari-rounding-down-on-subpixel-calculations)
- [percent (%) width rendered differently in different browser (firefox, safari, opera, chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051373/percent-width-rendered-differently-in-different-browser-firefox-safari-op)

Comment: I figured it was something like this, just wasn't sure if there was a quick fix.